# How can i set the check box "Allow Azure Services and Resources to access this server" via az cli cmds?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I create an azure server via the az cmds:

```
 az sql server create --name 'testserver' --resource-group 'testrg' --location 'northeurope' --admin-user <uname> --admin-password <upwd>
```

But when it creates the server , the check box, "Allow Azure Services and Resources to access this server" is not checked.

How can i create the server and at the same time check that check box , or do i need to do another az cmd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the "az sql server firewall-rule" command:

```
az sql server firewall-rule create --resource-group <resource group name> --server <azure sql name> -n <any name> --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0
```